# How to implement a sleeping api

Tags: node.js, express, process, backend

I currently have an api in express that sleeps for x amount of minuites and runs a function aftwards. I'm not too sure how process works since I am a beginner but I noticed I get an error message when x is too long. I was wondering if I am doing it the right way?

```
export function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}


app.post("/schedule", async(req, res) => {
    const { waitTime } = req.body;
    await sleep(waitTime);
    console.log("ran at", new Date()); //another function (will this function run?)
    res.status(200)
}
```

Will the console.log still run even though the waitTime is extremly high like 30 days? I get an error message `504 (Gateway Time-out)` in the client side. And also how do I make it so that I dont get an error?

Any resources related to this will be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Does your node.js app run behind a reverse proxy? How long sleep?

Comment: @Marc no it does not. Sleep is anytime between 1 minute to 30 days

Comment: Strage, 504 comes from a webserver that functions (mostly) as reverse proxy, but the service behind that does not answer fast enough. With 30 days, this is likle the problem, since most timeout is between 0 - 120 secs.

Comment: @Marc Oh wait actually it is a reverse proxy. Sorry im very new to this